# Can we use parameter in pull url of mercurial in teamcity

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, feature-branch

Need to know whether we can use parameter in PULL changes from URL in teamcity mercurial settings. My requirement is to pass the branch name parameter on run time. It works fine if I use the parameter in Default branch settings but I need to concatenate this setting with original URL

IN Teamcity VCS mercurial setting I am setting :-

```
Pull changes from: http://hg.test.local:8000#%env.branchName%
```

If I use the above setting it will go in an infinite loop of getting changes but nothing happens. 
Please guide how to concatenate parameter in URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teamcity does allow to use [Parameterized Version Control System roots](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+6.5#What%27sNewinTeamCity6.5-ParameterizedVersionControlSystemroots). I doubt your problem has something to do with env param. Try with a configuration paramter to test if that works.